# Clickable data displayed from mysql using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, forms

I'm not very good at JavaScript but here is my problem.

I have three pages: `page1.php`, `page2.php`, `page3.php`

On `page1.php`, I have a form for users to select  grade level they want to view, then the action is performed on `page2.php` -- displaying the list of all students in that grade.

This is the code for `page2.php`

```
     <?php

//database variables
require_once('admin_settings.php');


//these variables are from a form used to display the current data
$level = $_POST['level_group'];
$room = $_POST['room_group'];


$con=mysqli_connect("$host","$dbuser","$dbpass","$dbname");
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  } 
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT std_id, std_name FROM students  WHERE std_level LIKE '$level%' AND std_room LIKE '$room';");

//table 
echo"
<table border='1' id='mytable'>
<tr bgcolor = #99CCFF>
<th><b>Student ID</b></th>
<th><b>Name</b></th>
<th><b>Action</b></th>
</tr>";

//loop through the database



while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo"<form action='view_one_student.php' method='post'>";
  echo "<tr bgcolor = '#c0eae4n'  id = 'listings'>";
  echo "<td name= 'stdid'>" . $row['std_id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['std_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . '<input type="submit" value="view"> <input type="submit" value="sdq">' . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</form>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The question...now is How can I write the code on `page3.php` so that when users clicks on *view* or *sdq* button next to each column, the student ID should be captured, send a request to the  database, and query other data related to this particular student  such as age, address, phone..etc. and display them on that `page3.php`

Comment: Can you pass an input hidden with the student ID? So in page3 you need to search for that student and show the info.

Comment: On page 3, I can use PHP to capture the std_id which is displayed on page2. But the number of rows displayed from the database also depend on the number of students in that grade level..If there're 10 students, I will have to keep track of 10 different std_id, if there're 20, I'll have to keep track of 20 different std_id. Every row displayed contains a different students ID...

Comment: In page3, you want to display a detail of the selected student from the list of students that share a same grade level, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**page2.php**

You have to add a `hidden input` with the id of the student in page2.

```
<input type="hidden" value="'.$row["std_id"].'" name="std_id">
```

Change your `action` page to page3 (if that's where you want to display the student info: name, age...)

```
<form action='page3.php' method='post'>page2.php
```

The code for page2:

```
<?php

//database variables
require_once('admin_settings.php');


//these variables are from a form used to display the current data
$level = $_POST['level_group'];
$room = $_POST['room_group'];


$con=mysqli_connect("$host","$dbuser","$dbpass","$dbname");
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  } 
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT std_id, std_name FROM students  WHERE std_level LIKE '$level%' AND std_room LIKE '$room';");

//table 
echo"
<table border='1' id='mytable'>
<tr bgcolor = #99CCFF>
<th><b>Student ID</b></th>
<th><b>Name</b></th>
<th><b>Action</b></th>
</tr>";

//loop through the database



while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo"<form action='page3.php' method='post'>";
  echo "<tr bgcolor = '#c0eae4n'  id = 'listings'>";
  echo "<td name= 'stdid'>" . $row['std_id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['std_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td> <input type='hidden' value='" . $row["std_id"] . "' name='std_id'>";
  echo "<input type='submit' value='view'>";
  echo "<input type='submit' value='sdq'></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</form>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**page3.php**

A posible solution for page3 can be: (add your columns you need: age, address, phone..)

```
 <?php

    //database variables
    require_once('admin_settings.php');


    //these variables are from a form used to display the current data
    $id = $_POST['std_id'];

    $con=mysqli_connect("$host","$dbuser","$dbpass","$dbname");
    mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      } 
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM students  WHERE std_id ='$id';");



    echo '<h3>Student detail</h3>';

    //table 
    echo"
    <table border='1' id='mytable'>
    <tr bgcolor = #99CCFF>
    <th><b>Student ID</b></th>
    <th><b>Name</b></th>
    <th><b>Age</b></th>
    </tr>";


    //loop through the database

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo "<tr bgcolor = '#c0eae4n'  id = 'listings'>";
      echo "<td name= 'stdid'>" . $row['std_id'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['std_name'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['std_age'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      echo "</form>";
      }
    echo "</table>";


    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Lan..your're awesome. Wonder if there're more people on earth like you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code like this.  A hidden field will send the student id to the page of view_one_student.php.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo"<form action='view_one_student.php' method='post'>";
  echo "<tr bgcolor = '#c0eae4n'  id = 'listings'>";
  echo "<td name= 'stdid'>" . $row['std_id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['std_name'] . "</td>";
  echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$row["std_id"].'" name="std_id">';
  echo "<td>" . '<input type="submit" value="view"> <input type="submit" value="sdq">' . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</form>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
```

On view_one_student.php you have to catch that with:

```
$_POST["std_id"]
```

And eventually input that into a sql sentense in view_one_student.php:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE id=".$_POST["std_id"];
```

Thats the general idea.

Comment: I would suggest that you dident use the mysql api, its depricated.  rather use mysqli http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php